# Form Generator Keeps Generating No Form?

Tags: html

I'm trying to generate a form, and instead of generating a form, which allows different inputs to be taken, what happens is that my initial form tag gets put up above the elements I want in the form, and my closing form tag appears right after it. Why would this happen? Is there some reason?

Comment: how do you generate the form? what tool? what language?

Comment: What form generator are you talking about?

Comment: A wild guess: If we saw the markup and knew how you were "generating" the form, the quality of the answers would be higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably within a table but not inside one of the td tags.  Try making the form element the parent of said table.

Comment: It wasn't quite as wild a guess as you may be thinking.  I've screwed my forms up this way before and noticed the exact behavior described.